# Need some help in Oracle and PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I need help with the below code -

I have 2 tables - A and B

```
A | B
====================
1 | 1 
2 | 2
3 | 3
```

All i need is the row(1) from table A should be allowed to merge with row(2) and row(3) in tableB, likewise tableA row(2) should be allowed to merge with row(1) and row(3) of tableB and tableA row(3) should be allowed to merge with row(1) and row(2) of tableB.
[this is just an example]

======================

What I have tried:

I tried to use

```
$array = array('1=>1','2=>2','3=>');
$query ="select A from table where B='".$T."' union all select B from table where A='".$T."'";

    $array = array('1=>1','2=>2','3=>');
    $query ="select A from table where B='".$T."' union all select B from table where A='".$T."'";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
    $row = oci_execute($stid);
    $row = oci_fetch_row($stid);
    $oci_free_statement($stid);
```

I am not able to sure if we need to use slice/intersect/subset.
I have been trying to sort this using OCI_bind_by_array as well but no go, i have spent 3days but unable to find a solution.

Comment: what kind of final output you want?Post that in your question

Comment: Apologies! this output what i want -  row(1) from table A should be allowed to merge with row(2) and row(3) in tableB, likewise tableA row(2) should be allowed to merge with row(1) and row(3) of tableB and tableA row(3) should be allowed to merge with row(1) and row(2) of tableB.

Comment: @Auto123 Could you show the example of the expected in the same format as you did in the first grey block in your question?

Comment: sure.. Table A -----------------1 - 1,1-2,1-3; 2-1,2-2,2-3; 3-1,3-2,3-3; I hope this helps... i tried with cross join but unable to get the desired output

Comment: @Auto123 Try the following: `select A from table,table where A='".$T."' and B='".$T."'` I do not know if oracle support joining by comma, if not just use `table left join table`

Comment: yeah...i tried left join table and  that worked!! thanks alot..!